# What happens when the encryption algorithm receives an unsupported key size?

Tags: c++, c, encryption, passwords

I try to build an encryption program, and I use AES (256/192/128) from [realisation](https://github.com/SergeyBel/AES) I took from GitHub there is an exception if the key is not of these sizes. But I want to use the key as a password, in [KeePass](https://keepass.com) (they also encrypt with this algorithm) we can create passwords of different sizes. What should I do? I must add some padding bytes? Or I must use a hash algorithm to create passwords of the same size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>The accepted answer is not correct, misleading, and insecure!</strike>

**password-based key derivation (PBKDF), a small intro**

Normally, the key for AES must be generated uniformly randomly. It is hard for humans to memorize random keys, so we use passwords and derive keys from them. The correct way to convert a password into a key is using PBKDFs like PBKDF2, [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt), or better using [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2).

These key derivation functions take some parameters like `info, salt, iteration count, memory size, thread amount`, etc. These parameters will come from a very long line of countermeasure against password cracking methods.

- Salt is used to prevent the rainbow table.
- Iteration count is used to reduce the password search time of the attacker. Setting around 1M for PBKDF2 will slow the attacker 1M times.
- memory size is used to make the password hashing algorithm memory-hard so that an attacker cannot use massive GPU/ASIC to attack.
- thread amount is used to eliminate parallelization even in parallel CPUs.

These and similar parameters can be adjusted according to your target security ( look at the documentation before use).

**Use a PBKDF to get the desired key size**

Each of these PBKDFs can output the required amount of key sizes, 128,256, or more. Even one can [derive multiple keys from a single password](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75022/18298) by using different `info` or `salt` parameters.

- **Simply Hashing with SHA256 is totally wrong**, there are already rainbow tables for this, and even in [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/wiki/) can be used to massive parallel on GPUs to pawn your password. Never use,

  **In your case**, since the AES key is not random, **the attackers will not go to brute-force the AES, they will look for your
  password**, the [800K pawned list](https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords), and possibly your knowledge-based searches.

**Choosing a good password**

A good password is really important even you use a very strong PBKDF like the recent competition winner Argon2.

One should use [dicewire](https://www.eff.org/dice) or similarly [Bip39](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Seed_phrase) type password. [xkc936](https://xkcd.com/936/) tells this idea very well.

With a good password, you can even survive a badly designed password hashing login mechanism, however, you can't do good on [Facebook's openly stored password mechanism](https://www.theverge.com/2019/3/21/18275837/facebook-plain-text-password-storage-hundreds-millions-users), shame on them!

Comment: This is overkill for the OP's use case.  The hash is only being used as the encryption key for AES.  It's not being stored anywhere, so rainbow tables are a non-issue.  Their program could just as easily take a raw key, but they were looking for a way to expand whatever the user enters.

Comment: Not overkill, the AES normally must be uniformly randomly generated. If this is not the case the attacker will not look for the brute-forcing of the AES-key. They will search for the password. Using simply SHA256 will make their job easier. Therefore a PBKDF is a must! I've given an intro to PBKDFs, rainbow is part of it.

Comment: It should be the AES key must be uniformly generated.

Comment: And if you must have the feature that the same password entered in two places generates the same key?

Comment: I need to always remember salt and other parameters, or I can use them as a const parameters?

Comment: @THND You can store salt in the application. Salt is not secret. Salt is used to prevent rainbow tables, this is not your case since an attacker cannot get the hash of the password.

Comment: @Joshua If the hash of the password is not stored somewhere like a login system in which generally the hash of the password (and salt are) are stolen, then you don't need the salt, etc. However, you still need a fine parametrized PBKDF to be secure against the password brute-forcing and remember to use dicewire kinds of passwords. The salt and info have some other usage to, increase the randomness, and [derive more than one key with HKDF](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76589/18298) and [Argon2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75022/18298)

Answer (score 1):

When using a passphrase with a symmetric encryption algorithm, the common way of handling this is by hashing the passphrase then using enough bytes from the hash to build the encryption key.  This has the benefit of accepting a passphrase of any size without having to pad it (or trim it if too long).

For example, if your passphrase is "password", the SHA256 hash of this is (printed as hex) 5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8.  You can then use this hash as the key to AES256.  For AES128, use the first 16 bytes of the hash (i.e. 5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc62927).

Comment: This is not good advice for password hashing. We need special hash functions for password hashing like PBKDF2, Scrypt, and Argon2.